# Definite integration includes Exponential and Logarithmic functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, exponential-function

Does anyone have an idea of having solution for the following integration?

$$I=\int_0^\infty x^a e^{-b x} \log(1+cx)dx$$

where $a$ is a positive integer and $b,c>0$.

I found similar integral in eq. (2.6.23.4) in book " Integrals and Series: elementary functions. Vol.1", which is only valid for non-integer $a$.

Further, if I give same integral for known $a$ values such as $a=1,2,3,..$, then MATHEMATICA gives answers one by one. But it did not give for general $a$.

Comment: $I$ to always have the same form as a fraction where the numerator is $\alpha \times e^{b/c}\text{Ei}(-b/c)+\beta$

Comment: yes - need to identify $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Maybe,MMA code:`c^(-1 - a)*Gamma[1 + a]*Derivative[0, 1, 0][HypergeometricU][1 + a, 2 + a, b/c]`

Comment: is this the answer for $I$; or is this $\alpha$ or $\beta$?

Answer (score 3):

Start with $x=\frac t c$ and $k=\frac b c$ to make
$$I=\int_0^\infty x^a e^{-b x} \log(1+cx)\,dx=\frac 1{c^{a+1}}\int_0^\infty t^a\, e^{-k t} \,\log(1+t)\,dt$$ Even specifying that $a$ is integer and $k>0$, you will recieve for
$$J=\int_0^\infty t^a\, e^{-k t} \,\log(1+t)\,dt$$
$$ k \left(-k^2\right)^a\, J=k (-k)^a \Gamma (a) \, _2F_2(1,1;2,1-a;k)-$$ $$\pi  k^a \csc (\pi  a) \Gamma (a+1,-k)+$$ $$a
   \Gamma (a) \left(\pi  k^a \csc (\pi  a)-(-k)^a \log (k)+(-k)^a \psi
  (a+1)\right)$$ which present problems of indeterminate forms when you try $a=1,2,\cdots$.

I must confess that I prefer the individual cases which show some interesting patterns.

$$J_a=\frac 1 {k^{a+1}} \Big[P_{a-1}+Q_a\,e^k\, \text{Ei}(-k) \Big]$$ where $P_n$ and $Q_n$ are simple polynomials of degree $n$ in $k$.

Comment: is it possible to identify exact $P_n$ and $Q_n$ polynomials in general?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to derive a recursive formula for the integral based purely on b in a simpler case, then expanded to the current problem.

[image]

Through IBP,

[image]

Where a is any positive integer and b is a positive number. Then, you can solve for the first two cases individually through IBP.

[image]

[image]

Where [image] is the Exponential Integral function

Your problem can be derived from this through substitution as the relation:

[image]

Where the b/c term replaces the b in the I integral.

I couldn't find an explicit formula for the integral, but the recursion works from what I could tell and try. Let me know if someone finds one or I did something wrong.

Comment: How do you select $u$ and $dv$ from $I_a$ for IBP?

Comment: @Frey To derive the actual recursion relation, use the logarithm as _dv_. Logarithms "replicate" when integrated, giving you another logarithm to recreate _I_ in orders of lesser, same, or higher subscript.

Comment: $u=x^{a-1}e^{-bx}$ and $dv=log(1+x)dx$ is that you meant?

Comment: Can you please give few steps how you get $bI_{a+1} = (a-b)I_a +(a-1)I_{a-1} + \frac{(a-1)!}{b^{a}}$